# how to solve cannot run target compiler 'clang.cl' Output & error while parsing file C

Tags: qt, qml

I am getting an error when I compile or create a build of the QGC project

```
:-1: error: Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler 'clang-cl'.
```

Output:

Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

```
C:\Users\QT\Desktop\lavesh\qgroundcontrol\qgroundcontrol.pro:-1: error: Error while parsing file C:\Users\QT\Desktop\lavesh\qgroundcontrol\qgroundcontrol.pro. Giving up.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of the `*.pro` file used for compilation.  Please add the information about  the compiler(s) you use.

Comment: This is the .pro file content
contains (CONFIG, QGC_DISABLE_CUSTOM_BUILD) {
    message("Disable custom build override")
} else {
    exists($$PWD/custom/custom.pri) {
        message("Found custom build")
        CONFIG  += CustomBuild
        DEFINES += QGC_CUSTOM_BUILD
        # custom.pri must define:
        # CUSTOMCLASS  = YourIQGCCorePluginDerivation
        # CUSTOMHEADER = \"\\\"YourIQGCCorePluginDerivation.h\\\"\"
        include($$PWD/custom/custom.pri)
    }
}

Comment: I am using the ARMv7(MSVC 2017) compiler

Comment: Please paste the `.pro` file  to the question! Here it's illegible. Also, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting